# I can't move website created in famous on mobile device

Tags: mobile, touch, famous-angular

I've created website completely in angular + famous.

In desktop it's working great. When I try to open it in safari / chrome on iPhone it's working great as well but there is one problem. Using my finger I can't move page at all, only touch event is recognized, nothing more.

This is happening also in official examples. For example [examples/views/Scrollview/example.html](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/master/examples/views/Scrollview/example.html). If I rotate my iPhone 6 Plus to landscape I can't even access the browser toolbar to close the page, I need to kill the browser and start it again.

What I am suppose to do to fix this? Why is this even happening?

Comment: Which modules are you using? Are you using a Scrollview? Please paste some of the code so we can get a better look.

Comment: I linked the official example which "works" in the same way. You are not able to move website and therefore on iOS device you can't even open / hide adress bar in safari.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using Famous in `appMode`.  Try setting the following and see if that works:

`Engine.setOptions({appMode: false});`

When Famous is in appMode, it will add the following snippet when the context is created:

```
function initialize() {
    // prevent scrolling via browser
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, true);

    addRootClasses();
}
```

This is what prevents the browser page from moving.

Answer (score -1):

```
function initialize() { 
  // prevent scrolling via browser 
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {     
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }, true); 
  addRootClasses(); 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (This looks just like the code Joseph Carroll reports to be causing trouble: How is Petr Brazdil supposed to fix this?)